# React Virtualized List - How do you use the measureAllRows method on a List?

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm trying to render my list of data using the WindowScroller and List from react-virtualized, but for some reason, only a portion of my data is rendering. I've read over the docs and I believe I have all the necessary props...help is appreciated!

Taking my List out of the WindowScroller renders everything correctly, but I'd like to keep the WindowScroller to give scrolling controls to the parent element.

There are 100 items in my data set, but only a portion of them are rendering.

Here is a sandbox with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-gagarin-vczki1?file=/src/App.js

**UPDATE #1:**
I believe I've found the cause of my error! It seems that the height in the List element is the issue; it's not large enough thus cutting off my data. Because my List has no fixed height to begin with (height depends entirely on the number of children), I think I need a way to dynamically calculate the height of the List. I did find a method for List elements called `measureAllRows`, but I can't get it to work :( (see my sandbox above)

**UPDATE #2:**
I found a really hacky way to do it; by setting the List element's height prop to Infinity, I can get all of my items to render. This doesn't feel like a good way to solve the problem, but it does fix my issue with a dynamic list height.

**UPDATE #3:**
The answer below helped when just using AutoSizer, but I was curious... if I were to put my AutoSizer into a WindowScroller like so: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sunset-g4k3ly?file=/src/App.js, how could I achieve a similar fix for displaying all of my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say that the problem lies in one of the parent div for `WindowScroller` component which is causing this behaviour.

The overflow property cannot be set to auto for `WindowScroller` to work. If you try executing only the `windowScroller` part without modal window it works as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-ritchie-k938m0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm almost at my final workaround: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-saha-so14wh?file=/src/App.js, what I can't figure out is how to tell the list to remeasure the cached row heights when switching in between list lengths though...

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with similar problem and this worked for me, in your code try removing the `autoheight` parameter and get the height from the `autosizer`.

Reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-pine-2w2m8f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get rid of the inner scrolling on the list? (i.e. rather than having a scrollbar on the modal and on the inner list, can I just have the scrollbar on the modal?)

Comment: You can try something like this,
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hawking-2xygyr?file=/src/App.js